# wireless printing

Tags: networking, wireless, printing, epson

Useing Ubuntu 19.10 Epson ET 7750 printer works when printing A4 on Wi-Fi but doesn't respond when I try A3.

The printer is in another room from the computer and works fine on wi-fi with A4 and it is the same position as previous printers and all worked fine. Also on wi-fi test on printer it stated signal strength "excellent"

Comment: Does it work when you try A3 on a wired network?

Comment: that problem has been solved thank you.